# RegEx for match string containing ${reg.xx.xx. . . .}

Tags: regex, string-matching

Can someone please provide me a regex for match word like `${reg.employee.name}` or `${reg.gihan.anuruddha}` etc. In here word inside `${}` pattern and always starting reg. Rest of the word count after period can be vary. Some times you can have 3 word like `${reg.emp.name}` and sometimes for `${reg.tech.emp.name}` word count that divide from period(.) can be vary after `${reg.` part. I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Super simple version: `\$\{reg\..+?\}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should match your strings:

```
\$\{reg(\.[a-z]+)*\}
```

If it is literally 3 or 4 groups (including "reg"):

```
\$\{reg(\.[a-z]+){2,3}\}
```